# Question of Landau's book Mechanics: Find the time-ratio for different paths in configuration space

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, classical-mechanics

The **problem** is in the book *Mechanics* of Landau's lectures in theoretical physics

> Find the ratio of the times in the same path for particles having different masses but the same potential energy. (page 22 second edition)

The **problem**  doesn't give you much information but only the fact that the potential energy along the path remains the same. So the first (and only) thing that it is given is that $$U'=U$$ where $U$ is the potential energy.

**My first attempt:** Thinking in paths I tried to use the given relations $$t'/t = (l'/l)^{1-k/2}$$ $$E'/E = (l'/l)^k$$ and $$v'/v = (l'/l)^{k/2}$$ Where the above notations are respectively time, total energy and velocity. As he says *any mechanical quantities at corresponding times are in a ratio which is a power of $l'/l$*, I tried to find a relation for time and mass such that I know the answer of the **problem** is $t'/t = m'/m$ so, if we define

$$\bar{f} = \lim_{\tau \rightarrow \infty}\frac{1}{\tau}\int_{0}^{\tau}f(t)\mathrm{d}t$$ we can get that $$U' = U \Leftrightarrow \bar{U'} = \bar{U}$$

But this implies, because of the relation $\bar{U} = \frac{2E}{k+2}$ that $E' = E$ and that $\bar{T'} = \bar{T}$ so $$m'\bar{v'}^2 = m\bar{v}^2$$ such that we can put $m'/m = (v'/v)^{-2} = (l'/l)^{-k} = (t'/t)^{\frac{-k}{1-k/2}}$ so

> How I get that $\frac{-k}{1-k/2} = \frac{1}{2}$? Am I doing something wrong? There is a more nice approach to the problem?

**My second attempt:** Thinking in paths I thought that if I could find $l$ and $l'$ explicitly, may be as a function that arises from the action, the problem became easier. Is this possible?

[image]

Comment: Recently I found out that there already was [a similar question](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/69552/mechanical-similarity-in-landau) on interpreting this section of Landau. The author of the question presented his interpretation of Landau, and laid out some steps that were omitted in the book. In addition, a comment there mentioned a book on mechanical similarity by Sedov, which might also be a good treatise on this topic. I decided to add this comment just so that should anyone stumble upon this question in the future, they would know what other resources to refer to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe the intention of this section is to illustrate the idea that one can multiply the Lagrangian by a constant without affecting the equation of motion, therefore scaling the spatial/temporal dimensions of the problem without having to solve the equation all anew.

Thinking along these lines, I would attempt by first scaling time by a factor $\alpha$, and derive from that the scaling factor of the kinetic energy $T$. Since we are keeping the path invariant, velocity should be scaled by $\alpha^{-1}$, and since the mass is the same and that $T$ is quadratic in $v$, the kinetic energy should be scaled by $\alpha^{-2}$. Now suppose $U$ is scaled by $\beta$, then to keep the Lagrangian invariant up to a constant factor, we need $\alpha^{-2} = \beta$, which gives the desired scaling in time.

Comment: I'll do the calculations and see if what you say makes sense. So what happens is that Lagrangian times a constant can just construct another path that creates dependence in other dynamical components of the system?

Comment: I'm not quite sure what you're really asking. What I meant and what I believe Landau was trying to say is that if you multiply the Lagrangian by a constant, the equation of motion stays the same. Thus if a coordinate transform or a transform on some parameter of the system (such as scaling spatial coordinates by a constant factor, scaling potential energy by a constant factor, scaling mass by a constant factor, etc.) leaves the Lagrangian invariant up to a constant factor, then a solution to the original system can be scaled appropriately to obtain a solution to the new system.

Comment: Well, so if your interpretation of the problem is that Landau is trying to show that  "if you multiply the Lagrangian by a constant, the equation of motion stays the same" as you pointed out above what is the link between this and the statement "Find the ratio of the times in the same path for particles having different masses but the same potential energy. " To me the link is not obvious. This is my question in trying to understand your answer. The calculation seems not rigorous enough and I quite didn't understand fully the  step-by-step explication of the equations

Comment: For example, in this context we can put $t' = \alpha t$ and then $m'v'^2 = mv^2$ such that $m'/m = v^2/v'^2 = (dx/dt)^2/(dx'/dt')^2 = ((dx/dt)^2)\alpha^2/(dx/dt)^2$ such that $m'/m = \alpha^2 = (t'/t)^2$. But these calculations seems not rigorous and each step seems not obvious/trivial to me that this should be like the way it is.

Comment: @RafaelWagner In the first problem after the section, Landau is proposing a scaling of the system that alters the mass and time scale, but not the potential energy function or the length scale. Thus assuming time is scaled by $\alpha$ and mass by $\beta$, then the kinetic energy is scaled by $\beta \alpha^{-2}$, which should equal to 1 to keep the Lagrangian invariant. Your calculation is correct, and matches with the answer provided in the book. Could you elaborate what specifically seems not rigorous or non-obvious in this calculation?

Comment: 1) Why does $x' = x$ in the above relations?
2) What then are the connection for the paths $l$ and $l'$ and the factor $\alpha$?

Comment: @RafaelWagner 1) Because you want the new system to have the same length scale as the previous one, as indicated by the requirement "the same path" in both problems. 2) There is no connection, because the spatial coordinates are scaled by 1, and are not affected by the choice of $\alpha$.

Comment: 3)In my resoning we change the lagrangian $\mathcal{L} \rightarrow \mathcal{L}'$ by the factor in time, so, as the potential is the same, we look just to the kinetic energy. Should we try to solve the problem using path theory of, say, variational calculus?
4)Why the transformation $t \rightarrow t' = \alpha t$ changes the path in configuration space?

Comment: 3) I am not quite sure what you mean by "path theory of variational calculus", could you elaborate? 4) It doesn't.

Comment: Also, I think we should move this conversation to the chat, since comments are not for extended discussions. I am still trying to figure how to create one, or we could also just wait until the website creates one for us when this comment section gets too long.

Comment: I think you made yourself clear in these lest comments and that is why I accepted your answer as the correct one. I did the calculations and, with these arguments seems very reasonable to me that this is the correct approach. I expect that the comments and the answer should be useful to other users in the future.

Comment: I agree that these discussions can be useful. I was just trying to articulate a PhysicsSE policy.

Comment: Finally, to drive my point home, I just want to point out that here the $\rightarrow$s should be understood as a procedure of creating a new system similar to the original one. The new system should have spatial/temporal dimesnions and other parameters like mass proportional to the original one. If the potential is a homogeneous function in time/space or other parameters, then the Lagrangian will be the original one times a constant factor. The result of that is we don't have to solve the new system, but just use the solution to the old system with all the appropriate scaling applied.